# How can I plot a transcendental equation with an arbitrary constant?

Tags: plotting

I want to find the solutions to $\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{x^2}-1}=-\cot(x)$ graphically. This is how I'm going about doing it:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sqrt[c^2/x^2 - 1] == -Cot[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}], 
  {{c, 1}, -3 Pi,3 Pi}]
```

but I don't quite trust the graph I'm getting. I can't really distiguish the two equations. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NSolve` but it is so slow then I think that `Manipulate` is improper with this case.

```
plotting[c_] := Module[{s}, f[x_] = Sqrt[c^2/x^2 - 1];
  g[x_] = -Cot[x];
  s = NSolve[f[x] == g[x] && -3 π <= x <= 3 π, x] // Quiet;
  s = If[s =!= {}, {x, g[x]} /. s, {}];
  Grid[{{
     Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -3 π, 3 π}, 
      PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, Exclusions -> {Tan[x] == 0}, 
      ExclusionsStyle -> Dashing[Small], Epilog -> {Red, Point[s]},
      ImageSize -> 250],
     Pane[Grid[Prepend[s, {"x", "y"}], Frame -> True]]}}
   ]
  ]
```

Examples

```
plotting[5]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

But I tried `Manipulate` applied version like this with slow computation.

```
Manipulate[plotting[c], {{c, 6}, 0, 3 π}, ContinuousAction -> False]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 4):

Solve for `c` in terms of `x` and define two functions to be used with `ContourPlot`:

```
funcs = c + Join @@ FullSimplify[Solve[Sqrt[c^2/x^2 - 1] == -Cot[x], {c}]][[All, All, -1]]
```

> $\left\{c-x \sqrt{\csc ^2(x)},c+x \sqrt{\csc ^2(x)}\right\}$

`0`- contours give the `{c,x}` pairs that solve

> $\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{x^2}-1.}+\cot (x)=0$

We get the solutions  for specific values `γ` of `c` using `MeshFunctions` with `Mesh->{γ}` and post-processing the graphics output to get the coordinates of mesh points avoiding use of `NSolve` altogether:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{cp = ContourPlot[{funcs[[1]], funcs[[2]]}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {c, -3 Pi, 3 Pi},
     FrameLabel -> {Style["x", "Panel", 16], Style["c", "Panel", 16]},
     Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None, ImageSize -> 400, 
     MaxRecursion -> 4,
     ContourStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Red], Directive[Thick, Blue]},
     MeshStyle -> PointSize[.03], GridLines -> {None, {γ}}, Mesh -> {{γ}},
     MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"],
   Panel[Grid[Prepend[Join @@@ Cases[cp[[1]] // Normal,
        Point[x_] :> Reverse /@ {x}, {0, Infinity}], {Style["γ", "Panel", 16],
       Style["x", "Panel", 16]}], Dividers -> All, Spacings -> 5],
    Alignment -> Center, FrameMargins -> 30]}, Spacer[5]],
 {{γ, -5}, -3 Pi, 3 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Adding `PlotPoints->100` and changing the range of `x` to `{x, 0, 3 Pi}` we get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code

```
  conPlot =
  ContourPlot[
   Sqrt[c^2/x^2 - 1] == -Cot[x],
   {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {c, -3 Pi, 3 Pi},
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, c}),
   PlotPoints -> 101,
   MaxRecursion -> 3,
   Exclusions ->
    Thread[x == Range[-3 Pi, 3 Pi, Pi]],
   ImageSize -> {288, 288}];
```

Then

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   values =
    NSolve[{Sqrt[cc^2/x^2 - 1] == -Cot[x],
       -3 Pi <= x <= 3 Pi}, x, Reals] // Quiet,
   Show[
    conPlot,
    Graphics[{Red, Thin,
      Tooltip[
       Line[{{-3 Pi, cc}, {3 Pi, cc}}],
       StringForm["c = ``", Round[cc, 0.01]]],
      AbsolutePointSize[4],
      If[Length[values] > 0,
       Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@
        ({x, Round[cc, 0.01]} /. 
          values),
       Sequence[]]}]]}],
 {{cc, 6., "c"}, -9.42, 9.42, 0.01,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At least in my version of Mathematica, I cannot Plot an equation. I have to plot the two sides individually and I trust the result:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[{Sqrt[c^2/x^2 - 1], -Cot[x]}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}],
  {{c, 1}, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility is to solve the equation for c and plot c against x.

Here we go: take the square of the equation, add 1 on both sides and recognize 1+Cot[x]^2 = 1/Sin[x]^2. This gives us

```
c = +- x/Sin[x]
```

and the plot relevant for the graphic (!) solution is ... given the one of Bob Hanlon if we take into account only values of x for which -Cot[x]>=0 (because the square root must be non negative).

Regards,
Wolfgang